# Why is workplace holding the same icon from worldbuilding?

Tags: bug, status-completed, navigation, favicon

I don't know if this is the correct icon for the community, but I've found it weird at least and thought it would be a good idea to report.

[image]

Why is workplace holding the same icon from worldbuilding?

Comment: Added some tags based on their meaning on [meta.se].

Comment: Can you do a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5)? Should solve the issue.

Comment: It has solved indeed.